# Should failed (and inactive) shards fail the whole action and how?

Tags: error-handling, elasticsearch, action, sharding

I'm developing an Elasticsearch plugin that extract terms from fields that match a pattern. To get all the scaffolding done, I have started out from this plugin: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-index-termlist. So I extend `TransportBroadcastOperationAction`, and have it broadcast the request to `activePrimaryShardsGrouped`, and then in `newResponse`, I merge the shard results, count the failed shards, and pass the counter to the `BroadcastOperationResponse` constructor eventually.

I call this on the ES client like:

```
TermListResponse resp = TermListAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client)
        .setIndices("foo")
        .setFields("bar", "baaz").setPattern("wombat*")
        .execute().actionGet();
```

My problem is that the above **will not throw exception when there were failed shards**, although it indicates that in `resp.getFailedShards()`. Is it how it's supposed to be, or am I doing something wrong? Checking `resp.getFailedShards()` after all invocations doesn't look very safe, because someone can forget to do that and work with a partial term list accidentally.

Furthermore, the cause of the failed shards in my case was that the cluster was recently restarted and so the client could already connect but some shards weren't ready yet. I think it would nice if the action just waits for the broadcast target shards to become ready (with some timeout of course), just like search requests do, apparently. Maybe that means waiting for the "yellow" cluster health state, but *where* I'm supposed to do that, if I want to be true to the approach of ES?